How do I print a multiline make variable directly into a pipeline?
Consider a makefile with a multiline item:
define ITEM
line $$ONE
line $$TWO
endef

item:
  echo '$(ITEM)' | ... > $@

The problem is that as ITEM gets complex, I run the risk of getting quote errors and other problems when I echo the item.
I could also run with an export:
export ITEM
item:
  print "%s\n" '$${ITEM}' | ...

But I am not sure that is going to have the same bugs.
Is there some make function that will inject the contents of a variable directly into the shell, as if it were sent to /dev/stdin?
# e.g. something like:
$(info $ITEM) | ...

I understand that I can write the value directly to a file, which I'll be able to process via shell. But being able to write it directly to a pipeline would short circuit that.

this will have a series of commands, or introduce requirements like sponge
it may also cause me to have to shift from simple envsubst to heavier things like sed to allow in-place modification (to avoid installing sponge)

I also understand I can export the value to all subshells:

this may be problematic if my extension is included in a recursive make project, or a make project with a large amount of export-overhead (e.g. parameter?=vars that default to env values introduce a large amount of overhead when .SECONDEXPANSION is enabled)
in particular, exporting too much can break the performance of zsh tab completion for make, which is a soft requirement for mac users

But I have no proof exporting and echo "$$ITEM" or print("%s/\n") "$$ITEM" will have proper escapes. So I'll have to test it.

What is not "a way", but the intended best practice for doing this?
If the answer is: use $(file ..), and modify the file in place from there, then so be it; just want to make sure that is optimal.

This question is similar to: Output multiline variable to a file with GNU Make. In particular, it seems like the accepted solution could be modified by replacing > with |, which would solve your problem.

@NickODell I am not sure it does, unless there is make magic that will handle quote escaping during the export.  Otherwise, it is identical to what I've already done, and $(file ...) to some file, followed by processing that file would be a safer bet that saves me the work of experimenting and testing.

@NickODell also, exporting things like whole files to all subshells for an entire makefile environment can break make tab completion in zsh when recursive makefiles and ?= style variables are already used, so it is not really acceptable.

@NickODell (I've indicated I am aware of that solution in my question.  A simple: no, there is no better way than file, or export is guaranteed to work under all conditions would suffice)... I can't get either from ChatGPT.  Looking for a best practice.

Obviously you've discovered that $(info ...) | foo is impossible since $(info ...) is a make function that's expanded before make starts a shell and sends its output directly to make's stdout.  I think the answer to "best practice" is "don't do this" :)  But, if you do want to do it I think writing to a file and operating on the file is the most robust solution.

If the content you're trying to write is really static (that is it doesn't contain any make variables) you should look into using the $(value ...) function which will avoid having to escape all the $ in your define variable.

@MadScientist I wound up simplifying a bit. But, I think I can adapt the convention from the manual relatied to $@.in.

The usual solution for a complex variable expansion is to just write an external shell file. Or a script (perl/python/awk). Or even a special compiled tool to produce something which is needed for actual compilation.
It is not a must that everything would be part of makefile.
Rule of thumb here is: "if you struggling with variables, dollar signs, and quotation marks - maybe it is time to think of external script?"

Yeah, I am taking my initial implementation involving a few files, and condensing it into a makefile that is as simple as possible...but also a single file so that it is a portable tool.

I wanted to have this going straight to a file, but an intermediate file is probably the next best thing.  Thanks for the confirm that there isn't some esoteric trick to do this reliably.

After reviewing the accepted answer, I am going to adapt the convention from the manual:

For example, the file function can be useful if your build system has a limited command line size and your recipe runs a command that can accept arguments from a file as well. Many commands use the convention that an argument prefixed with an @ specifies a file containing more arguments. Then you might write your recipe in this way:

program: $(OBJECTS)
        $(file >$@.in,$^)
        $(CMD) $(CMDFLAGS) @$@.in
        @rm $@.in

And in my case, the intermediate file I'll have to create to stay simple with envsubst (rather than sed) will become the analog for the $@.in:
define new-file.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "$$FOO"
endef
 
new-file.sh:
  $(file >$@.tmp,$($@))
  cat $@.tmp | ... > $@
  @rm $@.tmp

Which will be something I'll have a good chance of doing the same way next time.

You need to escape $FOO in the definition of new-file.sh in this example.  See my comment above about $(value ...).
